# Process ElasticSearch message and visualize content

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am sending named entities frequency count logs to a kafka topic and reading the content using logstash.
I need to process the message I send and generate visualizations on that.
Here is my logstash.conf

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["processed-data"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "ner-kafka"
  }
}
```

I am able to see the message in the logs after creating an index in Kibana.
[image: Kibana Logs]

But I am not sure how I can process the message to separate the key value pairs and create visualizations.
I tried creating a separate script by using the ElasticSearch API, like below:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

#Tuples
data = [
    ('China', 8), ('DOT', 6), ('US', 6), ('AI', 5),  # ... and so on
]

entities_data = [{"entity": entity, "count": count} for entity, count in data]

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

index_name = "ner-kafka"
for idx, entity_data in enumerate(entities_data):
    es.index(index=index_name, doc_type='_doc', id=idx, body=entity_data)
```

This didn't work and I was wondering if there is another way to achieve the same using Kibana dashboard itself.

Can someone help or guide with this?